# How can I fix the align error and hover error of these <div> elements?

Tags: html, css

[Fixed] I'm trying to make these two `<div>` elements align when I hover over them, but it hasn't worked so far. I've tried using `display: inline-block`, but it still doesn't work, as shown. Another thing in the code is that the hover area is wrong. Any ideas on how to fix these problems? Here's my code:

```css
/* Please note that this is updated CSS and not
 * the original */

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital@0;1&display=swap');
* {
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  background-color: #121212;
  transition: 0.5s;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#c {
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(4vw + 4vh);
  top: calc(4vw + 4vh);
  transition: 0.5s;
  display: inline-flex;
  cursor: default;
  /* V3 of the CSS */
  overflow: hidden;
}

#ct {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
  /* display: inline-block; Removed in Revision 3 */
}

#c:hover #ct {
  width: 100%;
}

#ct span {
  white-space: nowrap;
  transition: inherit;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: calc(2vw + 2vh);
  color: rgb(100, 100, 100);
  padding-top: 3.5px;
}

#h {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: 0.5s;
  font-size: calc(2vw + 2vh);
  color: rgb(100, 100, 100);
  background: rgb(50, 50, 50);
  padding: 3.5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id='c'>
  <div id='ct'>
    <span>lorem ipsum dolor...&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
  </div>
  <span id='h'>?</span>
</div>
```

Update: The align error is fixed with the `<div>` and `<span>`, but the hover error remains.
Update 2: The errors are fully fixed. Thank you Zdravko Pernikov!

Comment: of course it goes to a new line... your hover style makes `#ct` go to 100% width... forcing `#h` to a new line.

Comment: the remained problem is that you want it the phrase to appear only when hovering on the question mark not when hovering on the whole line, am i right?

Comment: Yes, when you hover about 2 inches away from the question mark, the transition still occurs, but it shouldn't occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `display: inline-flex` in `#c` and also add `align-items: center` to align them vertically.

And for the hover -  add `overflow: hidden` and remove `display: inline-block;`
 from `#c` and in `#ct` change `width: 0%` to `width: 0`